# Login loop when trying Unity or Gnome, no problem with OpenBox or LXDE

Tags: unity, gnome, login, lightdm, lxde

After a freeze and a force shutdown of my pc I can no longer log into Unity or Gnome and Gnome(classic), entering the well known login loop about which several questions have been posted here.
When I log into OpenBox or LXDE however I do not enter the login loop.

I would very much rather keep being able to log into Unity.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem. I have tried all the solutions (.Xauthority rights, reinstalling lightDM, GDM, restarting lightdm) with no success.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz × 4

Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD OLAND (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)

Comment: What graphics card and what drivers are you running?

Comment: @CelticWarrior my graphics are Gallium 0.4 on AMD OLAND (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)

Answer (score 0):

After much pain, I found out it was a problem with my graphic card drivers. I have an AMD 8570 HD.

**Solution**

Get rid of ATI's propietary drivers and install the open source ones from Ubuntu. It will be necessary to purge fglrx* and make sure you install everything cleanly. There are lots of guides on askubuntu or ubuntu-related websites.